# REST url path parameter naming conventions

Tags: rest

Are there any naming conventions for generic parameter names in the REST url?

In my example, I want to get the address of a department based on the department ID or the organisation ID under which the department is coming under.

So the URL path parameter name deptOrOrgId - is it valid based on the naming conventions or 
should I use a generic name like sectionID or officeID or something to represent both department ID as well as Organisation ID?

Thanks.

Comment: Will be doing some check based on the deptOrOrgId? Like do some function if it is departmentID and do something else if its OrganisationID

Comment: it is purely to get the address of a department. ex, to get the address of an IT department the Id of the IT department is enough. If the ID of the organisation is given then I have to get the list of departments and find the IT department within it and return the IT department address. so my url parameter should accept departmentId or organisationId to return a department address.

Comment: The standard way to handle this is to have a constant url 
`http://hostname/[contextpath]/get?departmentId=[x]&organisationId=[y]`

Based on the available value in departmentId and organizationId, you need to handle this in your implementation like you mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 21):

Here is an additional couple of conventions regarding links and paths design in REST APIs that might help:

**1. Path Params vs Query String**

- Path params (`/parent/child1;child2`) are cool but query strings can express as much as path params can, are standard and explicit. ex:

  - `/parent?id=child1&id=child2`
  - or `/parent?id=child1;child2` ...etc

**2. Plural or singular**

Using plurals for each collection (or table, or folder) is good since it implies that the resource is a list of other resource

`/users` , `/users/user1`, `/users?active=true`

**Nesting resource : Default to no nesting unless there is a strong relation**

If a candidate child resource can exist independently of the parent, there is no point in nesting because you might end up with multiple paths for the same thing :

- `/departments/{departments}/employees/{employee}`
- `/branch-offices/{branch}/employees/{employee}`
- `/employees/{employee}`

With the latter you can do all of the rest :

- all employees in a department `/employees?department={department}`
- all employees in a branch `/employees?branch={branch}`

**3. Use nesting only on strong relations**

When the nested resource cannot exist outside the parent ([Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Composition) in UML terms for example)

- `/books/{book}/pages/{page}` You would never look for a page without  specifying a book
- `/players/{player}/stats}` (again, it depends on your domain models)

**4. Well ok... Use nested paths on not so strong relations too, but treat them as aliases**

Of course you might want to do nesting even if there is no strong relation, or tied resource lifecycle (the department/employee example) for some reason (DX, readability maybe ?). if you do, maybe you should consider the nested path as being an alias only :

- for `/departments/{department}/employees`
- internal rewrite `/employees?department={department}`

**5. If you want to HATEOAS, then path design should not be the top priority**

On the other hand, client readability is not important if you want to embrace REST's [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOS). API clients should not guess your links or have their templates hard coded. Instead, your API provides links that the clients follow. Example:

The root path might for example list all primary links:

```
GET /

200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{
   links:{
       "employees":"/url-for-employees{?department,branch,name}"
       "departments":"/them-deps"
   }
}
```

The links are intentionally ugly in this example. The one keyed *employees* is actually a [URL template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Template) with optional parameters.

The client API then looks for the link with key `employee` , (in this case /url-for-employees) — regardless of what it looks like — and calls it:

```
GET /url-for-employees

200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Link: </url-for-employees{?department,branch,name}>; rel="search",
</url-for-employees?page=2>; rel="next"

['body is an array containing the first set/page of employees']
```

Notice the Link header containing 2 links, one for search
and one to get the next page of employees (rel=next").

Benefits of HATEOS are out of scope here but at least one is that you are free to re-organize your paths without breaking API clients

**5. Last, try things on your file system**

One might use the file system to sketch/mock a RESTfull API:
create folders, files (and maybe symlinks/aliases/shortcuts) on your hard drive, browse them, change them, wash rinse and repeat until your happy with the structure :)

```
$ mkdir myapi
$ cd myapi
$ touch index.json
$ mkdir employees
$ touch employees/index.json
$ touch employees/smith.json
$ mkdir departments
$ touch departments/index.json
$ touch departments/accounting.json
$ mkdir departments/accounting
$ mkdir departments/accounting/employees
$ ln -s employees/smith.json departments/accounting/employees/smith.json
$ ls -l departments/accounting/employees
smith.json -> employees/smith.json
```

Answer (score 4):

Check section Resource URI Examples of 
[Naming Convention Tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html). Hope you will get your answer.

Also, this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RESTful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1214384739&sr=8-1)  defines three basic rules for url design which act as a great starting point:

> • Use path variables to encode hierarchy: /parent/child
>
> • Put punctuation characters in path variables to avoid implying
>   hierarchy where none exists: /parent/child1;child2
>
> • Use query variables to imply inputs into an algorithm, for example:
>   /search?q=jellyfish&start=20

Other guidelines include:

> • URIs should ideally not change over time.
>
> • Services offering a uniquely identifiable resource via a key should
>   use basic rest notation (e.g. /accounts/(accountid) )
>
> • Services offering optional search/filtering capabilities should use
>   query parameter ? key1 = value & key2 = value notation (e.g.
>   /instruments?ticker=FT)
>
> • Services expecting mandatory arguments over GET should have them as
>   path variables (e.g. /accounthistory/(fromdate)/(todate)
>
> • All rest service names should use strict low case names (e.g.
>   /client)
>
> • The elements of the URI should map to business entities and the
>   mapping should be consistent. For example a business entity named
>   contentpartner should be consistently referred to as contentpartner(s)
>   in all URIs (rather than a mix of partner, cp etc).  A good starting
>   point would be the name of the domain object.
>
> • Parameters that do not define a resource but qualify it (e.g. locale
>   which feeds into the translations of the data) should not form part of
>   the normal URI space.  Consider using headers or optional query
>   parameters for these
>
> • Use nouns, not verbs.  The power of REST comes through the fact
>   there is a limited verb set (operations) combined with a large set of
>   nouns (or resources). Consequently the manner in which these nouns are
>   constructed is of great importance.
>
> • Avoid suffixes.  When designingURIs it is paramount that they refer
>   to the thing that is being operated upon rather than the operation
>   being performed. Secondly, the client is interested in the resource -
>   not the implementation of the server software that powers the service.
>   It is desirable to avoid suffixes such as .jsp or .aspx.
>
> • Use Accepts Header for content negotiation
>
> • Keep It Intuitive. URIs should be human readable or guessable. The
>   easiest way to do this is to construct a URI hierarchy, grouping
>   related items together. Such patterns of category and subcategory are
>   very easy to understand.